# Performing one hot encoding inside a Lambda layer in Keras to avoid memory issues: problem

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I've made a sequential model in keras, for generating musical sequences. Something very simple, with LSTM and dense softmax. I have 333 possible musical events

I know that model.fit() needs all training data in memory, which is a problem if it is one hot encoded. So I give the model an integer as input, transform this to one hot encoding in a Lambda layer, and then use sparse categorical cross entropy for loss. Because each batch would be transformed to one hot encoding on the fly, I thought that this would sort out my memory issues. But instead, it hangs at the beginning of fitting, and fills up my memory, even with small batch size. Evidently, I'm not understanding something about how keras works, which is not surprising, given that I'm new to it (and on that note, please point out anything too naive in my code).

1) what is happening behind the scenes? What is it about keras that I'm not understanding? It seems like keras is going ahead and running the Lambda layer on all of my training examples before doing any training.

2) How can I solve this, and make keras do it truly on the fly? Can I solve it with `model.fit()`, which I'm currently using, or do I need `model.fit_generator()`, which to me looks like it could solve this rather easily?

Here is some of my code:

```
def musicmodel(Tx, n_a, n_values):
"""
Arguments:
Tx -- length of a sequence in the corpus
n_a -- the number of activations used in our model (for the LSTM)
n_values -- number of unique values in the music data 

Returns:
model -- a keras model
"""

# Define the input with a shape 
X = Input(shape=(Tx,))

# Define s0, initial hidden state for the decoder LSTM
a0 = Input(shape=(n_a,), name='a0')
c0 = Input(shape=(n_a,), name='c0')
a = a0
c = c0

# Create empty list to append the outputs to while iterating
outputs = []

# Step 2: Loop
for t in range(Tx):

    # select the "t"th time step from X. 
    x = Lambda(lambda x: x[:,t])(X)
    # We need the class represented in one hot fashion:
    x = Lambda(lambda x: tf.one_hot(K.cast(x, dtype='int32'), n_values))(x)
    # We then reshape x to be (1, n_values)
    x = reshapor(x)
    # Perform one step of the LSTM_cell
    a, _, c = LSTM_cell(x, initial_state=[a, c])
    # Apply densor to the hidden state output of LSTM_Cell
    out = densor(a)
    # Add the output to "outputs"
    outputs.append(out)

# Step 3: Create model instance
model = Model(inputs=[X,a0,c0],outputs=outputs)

return model
```

I then fit my model:

```
model = musicmodel(Tx, n_a, n_values)

opt = Adam(lr=0.01, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, decay=0.01)

model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

a0 = np.zeros((m, n_a))
c0 = np.zeros((m, n_a))

model.fit([X, a0, c0], list(Y), validation_split=0.25, epochs=600, verbose=2, batch_size=4)
```